# How to create tables for the following data model?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a data model for an online music streaming service, which has 4 tables: Payment, User, Song, Genre.

[image: IMGSHACK LINK FOR DATABASE STRUCTURE]

I have uploaded an image of the structure, which highlights the relationships between tables and the corresponding associative entities. (Apologies for the link, I am not allowed to post images yet)

The model must make sure that foreign keys work and that referential integrity holds.

I had an attempt at creating the data model, and assinging the respective foreign keys, but being a total beginner, I am not sure if I correctly created the data model and most importantly created the correct foreign key relationships, so that I can add and retrieve data.

Would anyone be willing to check my code? Thanks :)

Payment Table

```
CREATE TABLE Payment (

    PayID INTEGER,

    PayName CHAR (40),

    Primary Key (PayID)
);
```

Song Table

```
CREATE TABLE SONG (

    SongID Integer,
    Title VARCHAR (40),
    Album VARCHAR (30),
    Duration TIME,
    ReleaseYear DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (SongID)
);
```

Genre Table

```
CREATE TABLE GENRE (

    GenreID Integer,
    Name CHAR(35),
    Description VARCHAR (200),
    PRIMARY KEY (GenreID),

    CONSTRAINT foreinkey_holds_UserID FOREIGN KEY (UserID) 
    REFERENCES USER(UserID),

    CONSTRAINT foreignkey_holds_GenreID FOREIGN KEY (GenreID) 
    REFERENCES Genre(GenreID)
);
```

User Table

```
CREATE TABLE Users (

    UserID INTEGER, 
    UserFirst CHAR (40),
    UserLast CHAR (40),
    UserName VARCHAR (40),
    UserAddress VARCHAR (35),
    UserBirthdate DATE(),
    UserGender CHAR (1),
    UserEmail VARCHAR (35),

    PRIMARY KEY (UserID),

    CONSTRAINT foreignkey_holds_PayID FOREIGN KEY (PayID) 
    REFERENCES Payment(PayID),

    CONSTRAINT foreignkey_holds_SongID FOREIGN KEY (SongID) 
    REFERENCES Song(SongID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Payment Table

```
CREATE TABLE Payment (
    PayID INTEGER,
    PayName CHAR (40),
    Primary Key (PayID)
);
```

Genre Table

```
CREATE TABLE GENRE (
    GenreID Integer,
    Name CHAR(35),
    Description VARCHAR (200),
    PRIMARY KEY (GenreID)
);
```

Song Table (Many to One, between Song and Genre)

```
CREATE TABLE SONG (
    SongID Integer,
    GenreID Integer,
    Title VARCHAR (40),
    Album VARCHAR (30),
    Duration TIME(),
    ReleaseYear DATE(),
    PRIMARY KEY (SongID),
    CONSTRAINT foreignkey_holds_GenreID FOREIGN KEY (GenreID) 
    REFERENCES Genre(GenreID)
);
```

User Table

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserID INTEGER, 
    UserFirst CHAR (40),
    UserLast CHAR (40),
    UserName VARCHAR (40),
    UserAddress VARCHAR (35),
    UserBirthdate DATE(),
    UserGender CHAR (1),
    UserEmail VARCHAR (35),
    PRIMARY KEY (UserID)
);
```

Between User and Song, Many to Many relationship. So you need an associate table. Also better to have composite primary key on this table(PRIMARY KEY (UserID,SongID))

```
CREATE TABLE Users_Song (
UserID INTEGER, 
SongID Integer,
PRIMARY KEY (UserID,SongID),
CONSTRAINT fk_users_song_user FOREIGN KEY (UserID) 
    REFERENCES Users(UserID),
CONSTRAINT fk_users_song_song FOREIGN KEY (SongID) 
    REFERENCES SONG(SongID)
);
```

Again, Between Payment and User, Many to Many relationship. So you need an another associate table. Also have a composite primary key on this table as well (PRIMARY KEY (UserID,PayID))

```
CREATE TABLE Users_Payment (
UserID INTEGER,
PayID INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (UserID,PayID),
CONSTRAINT fk_users_payment_user FOREIGN KEY (UserID) 
    REFERENCES Users(UserID),
CONSTRAINT fk_users_payment_pay FOREIGN KEY (PayID) 
    REFERENCES Payment(PayID)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked wonders! I can't upvote yet, due to my reputation, but will do so after I get enough points.

Comment: I constructed a few queries to pull outcode, and it worked. However, having difficulty with the last query, which is how to retrieve the most popular genre amongst males (I assigned genders) would you have some kind of code example which I could apply?

Answer (score 0):

Missed some basic tactics here. For example, According to your model you cannot find who did payments. Create baseline or middle tables for many to many relationships. 
Eg: Payment and User tables create pay_user_middle which uses a composite key made of payment and user table PKs.